# Cellular network location service draining too much battery?(android)

Tags: android, networking, location, battery

we are developing an application in android which uses cellular(GSM) network location service (NOT GPS).Drains  battery very fast when we use this location service in our application...

I dont know what causes this draining .. any pitfalls, suggestions?

thanks for help

Comment: You can reduce the frequency with which you are requesting updates. 
The following link metions 2 more points http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Adjusting

Answer (score 2):

Instead of requiring the location every time you have to request the Last Known Location.
[**Get the Last Known Location**](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

check:
[**Fused Location Provider**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi)

> use the fused location provider to retrieve the device's last known
>   location. The fused location provider is one of the location APIs in
>   Google Play services. It manages the underlying location technology
>   and provides a simple API so that you can specify requirements at a
>   high level, like high accuracy or low power. It also optimizes the
>   device's use of battery power.

Read more:
[**Adjusting the model to save battery and data exchange**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Adjusting)

Comment: but I dont use any internet location. I get my location information from cellular network.